# how to print out contents of char** vector

Tags: c++, vector

SO,

I am looking to print out the contents of a vector; I have tried an iterator for it but that is no good

```
for(vector<char**>::const_iterator i=myVec.begin();i!=myVec.end();i++) {
   cout<<**i<<endl;
}
```

this does not work, what I am thinking is I will need two iterators (the above one will be the outer one, and the inner one would be as such:

```
  for(vector<char*>::const_iterator j=???;j!=??;j++) {....}
```

but I haven't been able to get it to work.

Thanks.

Comment: What does each element (`char**`) points to?

Comment: supposed to be basically a 2d array of words. so char** would point to a sentence, and char* would point to a word in that sentence, and myVec would have many of my sentences

Comment: Why aren't you using `std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >`?

Comment: But then by `char**` you lose information on the number of words in a sentence that you have to store elsewhere. In this sense you don't have any iterators to do your *inner loop*. Any reason for not using `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>` or a `boost::MultiArray`?

Comment: ...other than masochism? And how do you know the size of the C-style array of `char*` in each element of `myVec`?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Why dont you use std::vector with std::string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work just fine here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    const char* sentence1[] = {"foo", "bar", "baz"};
    const char* sentence2[] = {"xyzzy", "frob", "plugh"};
    std::vector<const char**> vec = {sentence1, sentence2};

    for (auto i : vec) {
        for (size_t w = 0; w < 3; ++w) {
            std::cout << i[w] << ' ';
        }
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

This will print:

```
foo bar baz xyzzy frob plugh
```

The above is C++11. If you don't have that, you'll need to change the vector initialization and the `for` loop:

```
std::vector<const char**> vec;
vec.push_back(sentence1);
vec.push_back(sentence2);

for (std::vector<const char**>::iterator it = vec.begin();
     it != vec.end(); ++it)
{
    for (size_t w = 0; w < 3; ++w) {
        std::cout << (*it)[w] << ' ';
    }
}
```

As you can imagine, you'll need to assume the same amount of words for each sentence. If you don't want that, you can create a new data structure that also holds the amount of words per sentence together with the vector of sentences.

Being a masochist is a good exercise, but for practical purposes you should probably switch to vectors so that you can iterate over the words more easily.